# Why does my Faroo API search only returns 10 results?

Tags: php, api, loops

I seem to only be receiving 10 results as when I access any index above 10 I get a Notice:

Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in /home/msc2012/12254822/public_html/safe_dir/safegoogle.php on line 146

There appear to. be no url parameters that let me access more results either and I think its supposed to default to 100.

$i=100 is a variable from Blekko loop that returns 100 result

```
if ($_POST['query'])
    {
        $query = urlencode ($_POST['query']);
        $fullUri = 'http://www.faroo.com/api?  
        q='.$query.'&start=1&length=10&l=en&src=web&f=json&key=';
        echo $fullUri;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullUri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data=curl_exec($ch);
        $js = json_decode($data);
        $o=0;
        foreach ($js -> results as $item)
        {
            $Faroo[$o] = "<h5>Faroo</h5><a href=\"{$item->url}\"> 
            {$item->title}</a>
            <p>$item->kwic}</p>";    
            $o++;

        }
    }
?> 


<?php
$agg =  $_POST['agg'];
$m=0;
$j=0;
switch ($agg)
{
    case 'Aggregated':
    while ($m<=$i)
    {
        echo $bing_results[$m];
        echo $Faroo[$m];
        echo $Blekko[$m];
        $m++;
    }         
    case 'Non-Aggregated':
    while ($m<=$i)
    {
        echo $Blekko[$m];
        $m++;
    }
    $m=0;
    while ($m<=$i)
    {
        echo $Faroo[$m];
        $m++;
    }
    $m=0;
    while ($m<=$i)
    {
        echo $bing_results[$m];
        $m++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried &start=1&length=100?

Comment: I have tried messing around with the parameters but there doesn't seem to be one for allotted for number of results in the url. So yeah, changing to 100 makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Faroo have default `Length (default=10; maximum=10)`

http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html#parameter